# Classification of cereal boxes

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering, computer-vision, object-detection

I have a database of labeled images of cereal boxes and am doing some object recognition, intending to do deep learning. All the boxes have similar square shapes, but have some different colors, images, fonts/text. I am looking to generate some features for the model. I have looked into HSV and SIFT features. Are there any interesting features to generate for this type of data. I know that everything depends on the dataset but was wondering if there are any new/interesting approaches for this sorts of object detection where the images have a similar shape but different label on the box. This would be similar to classifying beers, where the beer bottles look similar but recognizing the label is the task.

Comment: Are they photographs taken by hand that needs not have the box perfectly head-on, or are they perfect reproductions of the fronts of the boxes? Also, what's your dependent variable, just the brand of cereal?

Comment: Hi, they are not perfect and the brand is trying to be classified